# Programmatically filter Magento Sitemap

Tags: php, magento

Currently our sitemap shows every product and category we have. I would like to be able to filter those results to show ONLY products with a visibility of "Catalog/Search" and categories that contain products with a visibility of "Catalog/Search" Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own SE site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Sort of a broad question — you might be better off starting the project and then asking specific questions as they come up.

The method you'll want to target for a rewrite is in the `sitemap/sitemap` model.

```
public function generateXml()
{
    //...
}
```

This is the method that loads the site map data and generates the XML.  There's no elegant entry point for filtering what gets generated, so the two approaches I'd take are

- Call `parent::generateXml()` to generate the map as you normally would, bu then reload the file (`$this->getPath()`) and transform the document so the items you don't want aren't included, and the write the new file out over the old.
- Copy the existing code in `generateXML`, but add a conditional to the category loop around   line 155 in Magento CE 1.7

The former is cleaner — the later is quicker.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sitemap/catalog_product')->getCollection($storeId);

change this line in function  public function generateXml() of class Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap 
and apply filter.
modified line to be like this:

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection($storeId)->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);

This is a suggestion though with Magento standards modifying core files is not recommended so using above suggestion you can override above stated class and in your newly created class modify function generateXml()